# What is the minimum hardware support required for mutual exclusion of competing threads from a critical section?

Tags: multithreading, algorithm, atomic, mutual-exclusion

When several threads share common data, to avoid race conditions when it is being modified, mutual exclusion is required. These can be implemented if the hardware supports atomic `test-and-set` instruction.

But can we go even simpler? By having just atomic read operation and atomic write operation, is it possible to achieve mutual exclusion? [*Dekker's algorithm*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dekker%27s_algorithm) and [*Peterson's algorithm*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peterson%27s_algorithm) are some of the algorithms that can achieve mutual exclusion between just 2 processes if there exists atomic read and atomic write operations.

I have seen that *Peterson's algorithm* can be extended to involve N processes. The [algorithm](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/60857/145575) for that is like this:

```
lock(for Process i):

/* repeat for all partners */
for (count = 0; count < (NUMPROCS-1); count++) {
    flags[i] = count;                 // I think I'm in position "count" in the queue
    turn[count] = i;                  // and I'm the most recent process to think I'm in position "count"

    "wait until                       // wait until
     (for all k != i, flags[k]<count) // everyone thinks they're behind me 
     or (turn[count] != i)"           // or someone later than me thinks they're in position "count"

                                      // now I can update my estimated position to "count"+1 

 }                                    // now I'm at the head of the queue so I can start my critical section          


Unlock (for Process i):

/* tell everyone we are finished */
flags[i] = -1;                        // I'm not in the queue anymore
```

As far as I can think, this algorithm only requires atomic reads and atomic writes. But above algorithm is for cases where N is known. It cannot be extended to dynamic N case, since there concurrent array insert-allocation has to be protected again.

So, is there any known algorithm that can provide mutual exclusion among dynamic N threads, in a preemptive, multi-core environment with no `test-and-set` instruction? What if the starvation requirement is not there? Or, is it proven that this cannot be done without atomic `test-and-set`?

Sequentially consistent memory model is assumed, but mention if this is also not required. I think every hardware supports in some way to write a sequentially consistent program.

Comment: If threads all run on the same CPU, and if all you need is a single, global mutex, then simply disabling interrupts during critical sections may be a satisfactory solution. This technique actually is used in small embedded applications. Can't get much simpler than that.

Comment: @SolomonSlow no, I wanted for multicore computers. There just simply disabling interrupts wouldn't work.